# Using django with legacy authentication cookies

Tags: django, legacy-code, django-authentication

I have a large codebase in a homebrew python framework.  I'm going to be gradually moving the code to Django, but in the meantime need to support logging in via the old system.  The old system uses a cookie to identify the user after they have logged in.

I don't want users to log in via Django, but I do want to be able to use @login_required as well as several apps that rely on Django's auth system, such as the admin, django-tagging and django-comments.

What's the best way to integrate the two auth systems?  Both codebases are running within the same python process (via a wsgi middleware that switches apps per-request) and can load modules from each other as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get it working is probably to use a custom authentication middleware in Django.

There are a couple of example authentication middlewares in Django: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py

Comment: But what about support for off-the-shelf apps like django-tagging?  Those expect request.user to act like a django User model.

Comment: @GDorn: To make it compatible with the rest of Django your middleware should set `request.user` to a valid user in Django. Let the middleware read the cookie from the legacy authentication system and let it store a `User` object in `request.user`